# Чому темпль, а не синагога чи храм?

Tags: значення-слів

Нещодавно довелося перекладати текст, де ішлося про Чернівецький темпль. Спершу був спантеличений через це слово, але ввівши його в Гуглі побачив, що воно справді існує, та навіть більше, таких темплів в Україні є аж три: у [Львові](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2)), [Івано-Франківську](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA)) та [Чернівцях](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96)).

Очевидно, що це слово походить від англійського temple, однак цікаво те, що немає більше темплів крім цих ні в інших містах України чи навіть Росії. В СУМі цього слова немає також, а тому цікаво чи це діалектизм чи просто запозичення з англійської? А також цікавить чому саме "темпль", а не українське слово "храм" або ж просто "синагога"? Адже згідно до [словника синонімів](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/s/sinagoga/40-1-0-14596), синонімом до слова "синагога" буде саме "храм", а не "темпль".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиційно синагога юдеїв-реформістів зветься темпль (темпель). Дехто вважає, що підказкою має бути англіське слово, але насправді це слово з ідишу. Наведу деякі цитати.

> Сторіччям пізніше реформізм в іудаїзмі став виразником прямо
>   протилежну тенденцію - реформістські синагоги були великими,
>   величними, пишними будівлями. Реформісти називали свої синагоги
>   храмами (по-англійськи Темпл); в більшості з них були встановлені
>   органи і підмостки для хору. Лави стояли прямими рядами проти біми,
>   яка розташовувалася в глибині залу. В цілому реформістські синагоги
>   наслідували як у своїй архітектурі, так і в стилі літургії
>   християнської церкви.

[Электронная еврейская энциклопедия](http://eleven.co.il/judaism/community-synagogue/13810/)

> Темпель ‒ у перекладі з ідиш означає «святиня».

[ua.igotoworld.com](https://ua.igotoworld.com/ua/poi_object/69221_templ-sinagoga-ivano-frankovsk.htm)